# Word for range of foresight?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word for how far someone can think ahead, or simply the act of thinking ahead and playing out different scenarios in your head? Some examples this could be used for is how many moves ahead you think about in chess or how many years ahead in life you have plans for.

Some words I've thought about that aren't quite there are:

- Foresight: doesn't really talk about the act of planning.
- Discernment, insight: doesn't talk about the future.

Comment: Not *foresight* but *foresighted* might be right.

Why would *planner* or *futurist* not work?

Comment: *Foresight* does have the connotation of planning. The *lack* of foresight has the connotation of *no/poor* planning.

Answer (score 1):

[Prescience](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prescience)

As in, "He is a very talented chess player. He can predict his opponents moves with unrivalled prescience."

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for someone with expansive foresight. Or sagacity.

Answer (score -1):

"Prudent"

Adj. Of a person: acting with or showing forethought; having or exercising sound judgement in practical or financial affairs; circumspect, discreet, cautious; far-sighted.
[Edit: from the Oxford English Dictionary.]

Although perhaps this doesn't have precisely the connotations you are looking for.

Comment: Please cite your source and preferably include a link to it

Answer (score -1):

How about **anticipating** future possibilities ??